# Adding-up selected portion of vectors in a list, and outputting the total weight vector (using python)

Tags: python, vector

I have the following vectors in a list:

```
Q= [(0, 0.2815994630432826), (2, 0.678491614691639), (3, 0.678491614691639)]
```

I tried summing-up only the floating parts

`(ie Q= 0.2815994630432826 + 0.678491614691639 + 0.678491614691639)` as the first parts are indices which I do not want. See code below:

```
  aba=[]
  for doc in corpus_tfidf:
      con = round(np.sum(doc),2)
      aba.append(con)
  print aba
```

Here is the result I got: `(6.64)`
My code added up the indices and then the floats. My intention was to add-up only the float and out-put the total. Any ideas?, thanks in advance.

Note:(The for loop is because `Q` is just one out of hundreds of documents with such vectors).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (This requires that the elements you want to sum up are in the second position in the tuples)

```
>>> Q= [(0, 0.2815994630432826), (2, 0.678491614691639), (3, 0.678491614691639)]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sum(map(itemgetter(1), Q))
1.6385826924265605
```

Otherwise, you could just build up a list and `sum` that up.

```
>>> sum([val for _, val in Q])
1.6385826924265605
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use,

```
    reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x : x[1], Q))
```

for getting the sum of floating points in Q.

Map gets the second part of the tuple alone in a separate list and reduce calculates the sum of the elements of this new list.

Or simply, you could do this too

```
    sum([x[1] for x in Q])
```

Or this one,

```
    reduce(lambda x, y : (0, x[1] + y[1]), Q)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest and easier way to go for you would involve using sum function and list comprehension

```
>>> Q
[(0, 0.2815994630432826), (2, 0.678491614691639), (3, 0.678491614691639)]
>>> sum([i[1] for i in Q])
1.6385826924265605
>>>
```